# FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie stores data in which place

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

In the following code where the creating user accounts(userid, password) stores in?

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(RegisterUser.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);

Sameway, When LogIn, how it works?..(i.e)How the values are retrieved and compared to the data we are typing in the login page(userid, password)..Please explain the process..I am having doubt whether it is storted in ASPNETDB.MDF - > aspnet_Membership..If the values are stored here, then how application works when retrieving values from here to compare the data we typed in the form..Here the application I mean is Sample Application present in .NET4.0(Visual Studio 2010)..Pls help..

Comment: Please any one give solution for this..Thanks..

Comment: you need to write code to take user input and compare them with data stored in any database. After this step if data matches then you call setAuthCookie to create authentication cookie and set user as loggedin.
Read this - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** 24/12/2012

Below answer is out of date. The *venerable* **[FormsAuthentication.Authenticate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.authenticate.aspx)** is now marked as *obsolete* in ASP.NET 4 MVC 4.

MVC 4 ships with the new brand spanking [WebSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.aspx) authentication system which solves a lot of problems of the old system. Please look in to it unless your project is still using MVC 3 or below.

---

---

Short Answer is "It works very carefully."

Long answer...

User account details are (by default) stored in a SQL CE database (which is in the ASPNETDB.MDF file)

ASP.NET has a built-in Membership and Role Provider system to assist with authentication. This is an abstraction that ASP.NET uses to enable built-in support for accounts. By default, when you create an application, your web.config file is configured so your application uses a built-in implementation of this Membership Provider to allow your application to do the magic of reading and writing to the database, hashing or encrypting passwords, validating users .etc.

The code sample you got, is a part of Forms Authentication

> FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(RegisterUser.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);

It is the component that manages Authentication by default. When you perform the above call, ASP.NET Forms authentication system encrypts the username and a session data and stores it in a cookie on your user's browser. (This cookie is removed when you call FormsAutentication.SignOut() )

This cookie is transmitted to your server for every request. So, for each request, FormsAuthentication checks and validates this (decrypts it, check who the user is, validates the session is not expired, and set some properties in the application so your code can know which use is making the request).

If the  /* createPersistentCookie */ parameter is set, the cookie is set as persistent, which means the cookie doesn't get deleted when you close and re-open the browser while logged in. This is same as you logging into, say Facebook, and tick the 'Remember Me' check box, and the default implementation of the project created by Visual Studio does exactly this on your log in page.

Hopefully now you have a better understanding about what's happening in the login process. Because of the way these are implemented in ASP.NET, you can easily configure, extend or replace the functionality with your own implementation if you like.

To better understand how things work, follow this article on how to implement a custom Membership Provider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx

I should tell you that if you're new to ASP.NET, reading on how Membership and Authentication works may be overwhelming. (I personally spent the last couple of days trying to understand and write a custom Membership provider to match my requirements. It was a bit frustrating so I took a break to answer you and refresh my mind with the basics.)

If you're happy with how the existing system works, just use it. It doesn't hurt to implement a custom provider to understand how it works. But the built-in system has went through a lot of testing for the last decade and proven to be working. So why not use it ? I've seen multiple custom implementations on different sites that try to replace the existing Membership system, just because they don't fully understand it. Most of these implementations end up re-writing what is already available, and falls short when it comes to extensibility and security. Just like a wise man once said "Don't fix it, if it ain't broken".